# to change Status Bar text colour to white permanently throughout my app in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I changed the status bar text colour to white,when I open  camera roll in my app, it again sets status bar text colour to black, and when I dismiss camera roll status bar in my app has black text.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}
```

solved my problemmm

Comment: add this method in your view controller

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with out writing code

On you project plist file:

Set the

> Status bar style:
>
> UIStatusBarStyleLightContent

View controller-based status bar appearance: NO

Status bar is initially hidden: NO

[image]

Comment: Your answer is correct but when i m trying to use camera library again changing to black